# Can anyone help to read the seals?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

can anyone help me reading these seals? I found these on three zisha 紫砂 teapots in my local store.

One:

[image]

Two:

[image]

Three:

[image]

Comment: 新君製壺，劉?鳳製，陳占英製 . 新君製壺 is a company's name, 劉?鳳 and 陳占英 are person names

Comment: Second seal is 劉春鳳製

Comment: The word is 萅, 同“春”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

新君製壺 - Xinjun Pot Making

劉春鳳製 - Made by Liu Chunfeng

陳占英製 - Made by Chen Zhanying

新君製壺 is a company's name, 劉春鳳 and 陳占英 are person names